# Empty string parsing ntpq command result

Tags: java, unix, process, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I'm parsing the result of executing this composite command

```
  ntpq -c peers | awk ' $0 ~ /^*/ {print $9}'
```

in order to obtain the offset of the active ntp server.

This is the java code used and executed periodically

```
 public Double getClockOffset() {
    Double localClockOffset = null;

    try {

        String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", 
                        "-c", 
                        "ntpq -c peers | awk \' $0 ~ /^\\*/ {print $9}\'"};

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = buf.readLine();

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(line)) {
            localClockOffset = Double.parseDouble(line.trim());
        } else {
            // Log "NTP -> Empty line - No active servers - Unsynchronized"
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log exception
    }

    return localClockOffset;
}
```

ntpq result example

```
>      remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
> ==============================================================================
> *server001s1     .LOCL.           1 u   33   64  377    0.111   -0.017   0.011
> +server002s1     10.30.10.6       2 u   42   64  377    0.106   -0.006   0.027
> +server003s1     10.30.10.6       2 u   13   64  377    0.120   -0.009   0.016
```

Notice that **awk** searchs the first line beginnig with '*' and extracts its ninth column. In the example: -0.017

The problem is that sometimes I'm obtaining the no-active-servers log message - intended to appear when there is no server with '*'- while the execution of the command through the console returns a number.

I know that I'm not closing the `BufferedReader` in that code but is that the reason of this behaviour? A new instance is being created (and left open until garbage collecting) in each method invocation but I think that it shouldn't be the cause of this problem.

Comment: Why not closing the buffer if you finish reading? 
One thing to consider: I don't think that you need to wait for the process to exit before getting the input stream and start reading.

Comment: @breezee I've post my original code. It was a slip. I've already closed the buffer but I'm not sure if that was the reason of the strange behaviour described

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: Thanks for the link @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Runtime.exec()` simply invokes the ProcessBuilder inside it, like that:

```
public Process More ...exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)
    throws IOException {
    return new ProcessBuilder(cmdarray)
        .environment(envp)
        .directory(dir)
        .start();
}
```

see [OpenJDK Runtime.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Runtime.java#Runtime.exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.io.File%29)

So there is nothing wrong with using it instead of the `ProcessBuilder` as is.

The problem is that you invoke:

```
p.waitFor();
```

before you obtained the `InputStream`.

Which means that the process will be already terminated, by the time you obtain the `InputStream`, and the output stream data might be or might not be available to you, depending on the OS buffering implementation nuances and precise timing of the operations.

So, if you move the `waitFor()` to the bottom, your code should start working more reliably.

Under Linux however you should normally be able to read the remaining data from the PIPE buffer, even after the writing process has ended.

And the [UNIXProcess](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/classes/java/lang/UNIXProcess.java#l526) implementation in OpenJDK, actually makes an explicit use of that, and tries to drain the remaining data, once the process has exited, so that file descriptor can be reclaimed:

```
/** Called by the process reaper thread when the process exits. */
synchronized void processExited() {
    synchronized (closeLock) {
        try {
            InputStream in = this.in;
            // this stream is closed if and only if: in == null
            if (in != null) {
                byte[] stragglers = drainInputStream(in);
                in.close();
                this.in = (stragglers == null) ?
                    ProcessBuilder.NullInputStream.INSTANCE :
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(stragglers);
            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

And this seems to work reliable enough, at least in my tests, so it would be nice to know which specific version of Linux|Unix and JRE your are running.

Have you also considered the possibility of an application-level problem ?
I.e. `ntpq` is not really guaranteed to always return a `*` row.

So, it would be nice to remove the `awk` part from your pipe, to see if there will be some output at all the times.

Another thing to note is that if one of your shell pipeline steps fails (e.g. the ntpq itself), you will also get an empty output, so you will have to track the STDERR as well (e.g. by merging it with STDOUT via the `ProcessBuilder`).

**Sidenote**

Doing `waitFor` before you start consuming the data, is a bad idea in any case, as if your external process will produce enough output to fill the pipe buffer, it will just hang waiting for someone to read it, which will never happen, as your Java process will be locked in `waitFor` at the same time.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer. In relation with your statement about ntpq not returning an '*', I'm not proud of the algorithm but I can not change it. The problem was that ntpq was returning it and the program showing "No * found". My code is running in a Red Hat 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 with a jre 1.8.0_112-b15 but I think that you have already answered my question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by Andrew Thompson, you shall try `ProcessBuilder` instead.

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", 
                        "-c", 
                        "ntpq -c peers | awk \' $0 ~ /^\\*/ {print $9}\'"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process proc = pb.start();
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
   localClockOffset = Double.parseDouble(line.trim());
   break;
}

proc.destroy();
```

Ref [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: I'm already using ProcessBuilder. I found a few days ago this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30629442/2553194 but I want to know exactly why my original approach fails sometimes. What is happening there?

Comment: What I understands is `p.waitFor();` just causes the current thread to wait,and the stream that is fetched "after" a waitFor will depend on many factors. As stated in example here https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2, if you will start your reading in a separate thread and will read but stdout and stderr, then you will get predictable result as well.

Comment: "Many factors"? A bit unaccurate, isn't it? Also, I've just read your answer completely, why do I need a loop? I just want to read a single line. I still don't know exactly why sometimes the above code works but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Finally we have found the real problem.

I'm not gonna change the accepted anwser, I think that it's useful too but maybe someone can learn from our experience.

My java program is launched with a shell script. When we execute the script manually, `ntpq` command is found and invoked successfully. The problem arises when the software is fully deployed. In the final environment we've got a cron scheduled demon that keeps our program alive but `PATH` established by cron is different from the `PATH` that our profile has got assigned.

`PATH` used by cron:

```
.:/usr/bin:/bin
```

`PATH` that we got login for launching the script manually:

```
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/local/users/nor:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib:.
```

Usually `ntpq` is in

```
/usr/sbin/ntpq
```

After we found the key of our problem, I search StackOverflow and got this relevant question where the problem is better explained and solved.

[How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)